# Android broadcast receiver doesn't receive ACTION_SCREEN_ON

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, screen

I tried to register the receiver in my service with the following code:

```
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);
ScreenReceiver SR = new ScreenReceiver();
registerReceiver(SR, filter);
```

and this is my broadcast receiver:

```
public class ScreenReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver { 
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        System.out.println("RECEIVED");
    }
}
```

I have even declared it in the manifest but without any filters:

```
<receiver android:name=".ScreenReceiver" android:enabled="true" />
```

But whatever I do, I can't seem to be able to receive the intent when I turn my screen on.

Is this intent disabled in android ICS or JB or am i missing something?

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's work for me on Android 4.0.4

```
BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent == null)
            return;
        //do something you need when broadcast received

    }
};
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter()
filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);
filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);

context.registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
```

As for register receiver with action Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON and Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF in Manifest.xml it don't help because Android code in [PowerManagerService.java](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.3.7_r1/com/android/server/PowerManagerService.java#PowerManagerService) following:

```
...
mScreenOnIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);
mScreenOnIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_RECEIVER_REGISTERED_ONLY);
mScreenOffIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
mScreenOffIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_RECEIVER_REGISTERED_ONLY); 
...
```

Comment: Hi there, thanks but I don't see how your code is different from the one of the person who asks this question - I don't see what is wrong with the person's code. Can you elaborate?

Comment: It's mostly connected to answering "Is this intent disabled in android ICS or JB or am i missing something?". I use this code on Android 4.0.4 and it's work perfectly for me.

Comment: Android 5.1.1 here, thanks for answering. I've tried both OP's method and this method and for some reason only this one works. Do you think it has to do with the method of writing within the activity (both codes should be identical though?) or is it something with the manifest

Answer (score 4):

Read this tutorial 
[Handling Screen OFF and Screen ON Intents](http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/24/handling-screen-off-and-screen-on-intents/), 
it could help you.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should check which intent is coming inside your `onReceive()` method:

```
if(intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON)
{
    ...
}
```

Also, have you tried putting a breakpoint in there?

Other advice, instead of using `System.out.println` use the API native log which would be in your case

```
Log.i("ScreenReceiver""RECEIVED");
```

And you can read the log in the logcat.