# Dock and screen off broadcast service

Tags: android

First,I have searched for the question and found about 2-3 stackoverflow links but I dont get a definite answer.Basically,my app needs to start a activity when the phone is docked (any type of dock) or when screen is off.I registered a broadcast receiver in manifest:

```
<receiver android:name=".BootReciever">
<intent-filter >
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_DOCK_EVENT"/>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SCREEN_OFF"/>
</intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

And in my class:

```
public class BootReciever extends BroadcastReceiver{
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    String action = intent.getAction();
if(action.equals(Intent.ACTION_DOCK_EVENT)){
        //work for dock
    }

    if (action.equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)) {
        //work for screen off
    }

}
}
```

But both doesnt work.My work is not done is both the cases.I read about I have to do it in services but since I have never worked with my own service and I fell android.developers.com is a bit of pro friendly,I have difficulty getting it to work.Can somebody say me how to I achieve the above?And my app has to listen for it as long service.So even when my app isnt in foreground.Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `SCREEN_OFF` has definitely to be registered programatically (see [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12681884/android-broadcast-receiver-doesnt-receive-action-screen-on) for instance, it'a a [protected intent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)):

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    BroadcastReceiver receiver;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        try {
            receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
                @Override
                public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                    Log.d("TAG", "on or off");
                }
            };
            IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
            filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
            Log.d("TAG", "Register receiver");
            registerReceiver(receiver, filter);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("TAG", "Caught: " + e.getStackTrace());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

        try {
            Log.d("TAG", "Unregister receiver");
            unregisterReceiver(receiver);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("TAG", "Caught: " + e.getStackTrace());
        }
    }
}
```

For the `ACTION_DOCK_EVENT` I would assume something else being wrong. May be it doesn't work due to the combination with `ACTION_SCREEN_OFF`, may be it's due to a naming issue (I wouldn't expect a relative path for `.BootReciever`, for instance; check, if a full qualified class  name works).

Hope this helps .... Cheers!

Comment: thanks gonna check both.Althought this one will be first because I could put this in my Broadcast receiver class and check it out.Also I have planned to intent a class on bootcomplete.Will try it soon and let know the result!Thanks once again!

Comment: I tried both the answer and the 2nd answer from [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12681884/android-broadcast-receiver-doesnt-receive-action-screen-on) link.But it doesnt work for me.Its seems I feel it hard to implement this small function?I dont know what to do.It is wrong to ask but,can anybody provide me a example app source which runs a service to register a screen off and run a block of code upon screenoff?Thanks and sorry for the troubles...

Comment: See complete activity sample above (it's a working example from a newly created app)

Comment: Sorry...I added the above code to my mainactivity but the above doesn't log anything and I even tried to add a toast and it doesn't show up...Is there something to with my api levels?My min api is 8 and target is 17

Comment: Mmmmhhh, that sounds strange. Have you also tried to create a new app? It took me just a couple of minutes to get that sample running. Are you sure you have removed all filters from log cat?

Comment: Works now after I removed the code and re added it.I think eclipse was playing tricks with me...And biggggg thanks!I learned to create a service and added your code to it and it too works flawlessly except that I still dont know how long the service is running.
Also my dock issue stay still which I will try to fix or bug Stackoverflow again :D.Thanks again and best answer selected but cant vote :)

Comment: You're welcome! Regarding the service: search for `START_STICKY` - it might stop after execution or run until it's stopped explicitely. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Receivers for these kinds of intents need to be registered dynamically in the code.

```
        this.receiver = new BootReceiver();
        final IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
        filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
        filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_DOCK_EVENT);
        this.registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
```

You could do this in any activity (register in onStart(), un-register in onStop(), see [visible lifetime](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html#ImplementingLifecycleCallbacks) section) or in you application object.

The problem with dynamic registration though is your application has to be started before BootReceiver can receive intents.

Comment: Should I put that in my main activity?And doesnt this need my application to be started manually unlike charger connected broadcast which works without starting app manually?
So should my work around be to register a boot complete broadcast and then call this code block?Sorry I'm new and I need to get every info in newbie way :)

Comment: If you don't have a service implemented and you need to restart a particular activity: yes, register the receiver in the `onCreate()` of that activity and unregister it in `onDestroy()`.

Comment: I tried both the answer and the 2nd answer from [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12681884/android-broadcast-receiver-doesnt-receive-action-screen-on) link.But it doesnt work for me.Its seems I feel it hard to implement this small function?I dont know what to do.It is wrong to ask but,can anybody provide me a example app source which runs a service to register a screen off and run a block of code upon screenoff?Thanks and sorry for the troubles....