# Listening to SCREEN_OFF action in android without registering

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, screen-off

People. I want to listen to on SCREEN_OFF of android for that I have declared a broadcast-receiver as

```
public class OnListenWOABC extends BroadcastReceiver {


@Override
public void onReceive(Context context_ext, Intent intent) {



     Log.d("lock","Screen went OFF");





    } 



}
```

And in my menifest.xml I have done as

```
<receiver android:exported="false" android:name="com.myapp.demo.OnListenWOABC">
<intent-filter>  
<action  android:name="android.intent.action.SCREEN_OFF" />  
</intent-filter>  
</receiver>
```

But my Receiver is not listening at all.
The problem is , I don't want to register the reciver in any activity, and want it to start without launching the app. on BOOT is working without even registering in any class.  Please help me out, and let me know if it is possible. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The SCREEN_OFF broadcast can't be registered in manifest, it must be registered in java code.The following actions can't be registered in manifest:

```
android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON
android.intent.action.SCREEN_OFF
android.intent.action.BATTERY_CHANGED
android.intent.action.CONFIGURATION_CHANGED
android.intent.action.TIME_TICK
```

Comment: So, can you list me some of the action which can listen without launching the application? ON_BOOT is working fine, apart from on_BOOT are there any?

Comment: is there any specific reason for not listening to SCREEN_OFF?? and thanks let me try and get back to you

Comment: I've updated the answer, except those five actions I listed (May be more,but  I just know these five actions), most of other broadcast actions can listen without launching the application

Comment: Am so sorry but am so blank. Can you just atleast list  one action which can listen without launching the app except ON_BOOT

Comment: May be this will help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12681884/android-broadcast-receiver-doesnt-receive-action-screen-on

Comment: Okay let me try with ACTION_DATE_CHANGED and thank you

Comment: Nope ACTION_DATE_CHANGED too not working. I guess there is no way to do so

Comment: ACTION_AIRPLANE_MODE_CHANGED this works fine on my device android 4.4

Comment: Well i want an action which the user may use more frequently :(

Comment: Ok, fine one from api : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html

Answer (score 0):

How about `TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING` which detects incoming call.