# broad cast receive does not show notifications

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcast

i am trying to receive notifications when the screen goes on or off. i registered a broad cast receiver as shown below.

but when i press the button on the top right on the edge, the receiver is called but the log statements shown in the code does not show.

please tell me know to correct it

**code**:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String action = intent.getAction();

    switch (action) {

    case Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON:
        Log.w(TAG, SubTag.msg("onReceive", "Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON"));
        break;
    case Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF:
        Log.w(TAG, SubTag.msg("onReceive", "Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF"));
        break;

    default:
        Log.w(TAG, SubTag.msg("onReceive", "UNHANDLED CASE"));
        break;
    }
}
```

**update**:

i registerd the rceiver in onstart as follows:

```
registerReceiver(this.mScreenReceiver, new IntentFilter(intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON))
```

registerReceiver(this.mScreenReceiver, new IntentFilter(intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF))

Comment: Did you register the receiver in the manifest? also `Log` doesn't appear on the screen, maybe you want to use a toast.

Comment: @SaNtoRiaN do u mean a permission? no i have not added any permssions. should i? please let me know which one

Comment: @user2121 , have you tried Log.d instead of Log.w (may be I just can't see Log.w in preferences) ? Have to tried to catch 'onRecieve' by debug breakpoint?

Comment: @user2121 ,  have you tried directly this example : http://stackoverflow.com/a/14834160/1979882 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a permission, you should register your broadcast in the manifest. Inside the `application` tags in the manifest, write this code but first change the name to your broadcast class name

```
<receiver android:name=".your_class_name_here" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SCREEN_OFF" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

**Update**
Try this broadcast

```
private BroadcastReceiver ScreenActions = new BroadcastReceiver() {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.i("BroadcastReceiver", "Broadcast is called");

        if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON)) {
            Log.i("BroadcastReceiver", "Screen ON");
        } else if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)) {
            Log.i("BroadcastReceiver", "Screen OFF");
        }

    }
};
```

and inside your `onStart()` register it

```
registerReceiver(ScreenActions, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON));
registerReceiver(ScreenActions, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF));
```

Comment: ok, but i am alos using bluetooth and i have not registered it in the manifest and it is working fine!! i registered my receivers in  onStart()

Comment: @user2121 Yeah you can do one of 2 methods, in manifest or in onStart() , but the important is to register it

Comment: so i registered the screen receiver in onstart() and it is not working

Comment: @user2121 Did you try a `log` outside the `switch` to make sure that the receiver is called?

Comment: sorry i updated ur answer by mistake. and i tried now to place the log inside the receiver and it is not getting called

Comment: @user2121 No problem :), I think you should add also `registerReceiver(this.mScreenReceiver, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF));` to listen to screen off too

Comment: yes i added both, but still there is no notification received

Comment: @user2121 I updated my answer, try that broadcast, it's working for me

Comment: i tried your updated answer but i am not getting any thing though.?!!

Comment: @user2121 Sorry it's a silly question, but do you lock your screen and unlock it? and are you sure that it doesn't appear in the logcat?? because it's working well here

Comment: yes is lock the screen and unlock it, and there is alog in onstart and onstop to report registering and unregiteration, those log show up but any other log from the screen receiver do not

Comment: @user2121 What do you mean by show up? in the logcat or on the screen?

Comment: lin the logcat i mean

Comment: @user2121 I've made a project in eclipse, you can import it or use the code in the src file http://www.mediafire.com/download/tjfdwzs4fusllqo/ScreenOnOff.rar I can find no other solution to that problem